# Misclassification using VGG16 Net

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

I use Faster RCNN to classify 33 items. But most of them are misclassified among each other. All items are snack packets and sweet packets like in the link below.

https://redmart.com/product/lays-salt-and-vinegar-potato-chips

[https://www.google.com/search?q=ice+breakers&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5qqXMofHfAhUQY48KHbIgCO8Q_AUIDigB&biw=1855&bih=953#imgrc=TVDtryRBYCPlnM:](https://www.google.com/search?q=ice%20breakers&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5qqXMofHfAhUQY48KHbIgCO8Q_AUIDigB&biw=1855&bih=953#imgrc=TVDtryRBYCPlnM:)

[https://www.google.com/search?biw=1855&bih=953&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=S5g-XPatEMTVvATZgLiwDw&q=disney+frozen+egg&oq=disney+frozen+egg&gs_l=img.3..0.6353.6886..7047...0.0..0.43.116.3......1....1..gws-wiz-img.OSreIYZziXU#imgrc=TQVYPtSi--E7eM:](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1855&bih=953&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=S5g-XPatEMTVvATZgLiwDw&q=disney%20frozen%20egg&oq=disney%20frozen%20egg&gs_l=img.3..0.6353.6886..7047...0.0..0.43.116.3......1....1..gws-wiz-img.OSreIYZziXU#imgrc=TQVYPtSi--E7eM:)

So color and shape are similar.
What could be the best way to solve this misclassification problem?

Comment: Because all are having same shapes, that confuse your model. But you can give a chance to fine-tuning on this item, by collecting some data.

Comment: @AnkishBansal can you please explain a bit more how to fine-tune, so that I have some clues. What I am doing now is I make two separate groups to train on two different models. But I prefer single model to use. If no choice, I have to go that way. Any explanation how to fine tune?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fine tuning** is a way to use features, learned  on some big dataset, in our problem, which means instead of training the complete network again, we `freeze` out weights of the lower layer of the network and add few layers at the end of network, as per requirement. Now we train it on our data-set again. So the **advantage** here is that, we don't need to train `all-millions` of parameters, but few only. Another is that we don't need `large-dataset` to fine-tune.

More you can find [here](https://github.com/sebastianbk/finetuned-resnet50-keras). This is [another-useful](https://gogul09.github.io/software/flower-recognition-deep-learning) resource, where author has explained this in more detail(with code).

**Note**: This is also known as `transfer-learning`.

Comment: My training used pre-trained model of VGG16. Pretrained model is trained with big dataset, in that case I can do tuning as you mentioned. Is it? I don't need to train the  whole network and just finetune the later part of the network.

Comment: Yes, you understood right. You can use pretrained weight for VGG, which you can find easily in tensorflow or keras, which is trained on `Imagenet` dataset, and it have millions of images and 1000 of categories. Also VGG has `billions` of parameters, which is very expensive to train by yourself. So fine-tune helps a lots.